# How to decompress RPM file in Java?

Tags: java, rpm, compression

Recently, I just wrote an eclipse plugin to auto deploy one specific Java EE application to my tomcat server. During the process, there was a step which needed to decompress RPM file downloaded from build server. When I searched the solution from Google, nothing found. I just know that there  exists a commons compress lib to decompress various archived files, such as gzip/cpio/ar/tar etc. But for RPM file, it doesn't work. Can anyone else know how to decompress RPM file using Java? Thanks in advance.

Comment: Can't you install the RPM using the local package manager?

Comment: @JonasWielicki No, this process is just one step in my eclipse plugin program. I just want to handle this process using Java language.

Comment: But calling the local package manager from within java instead of installing the RPM by hand would avoid duplicate installations, conflicts and allow clean removal.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As comments above, I just tried the method using 7-zip command line method, it works!!! For the usage of 7-zip command line, you can visit the 7-zip official website or manual book existed in your install directory. Just a kind reminder: be sure to use 32-bit version for the OS compatibility.

Answer (score 0):

I have not actually tried this one but it promises the functionality you are looking for:

```
http://code.google.com/p/redline-rpm
```

Comment: thanks for your recommendation. I tried the tool you mentioned, but unfortunately, it did not meet my requirements and not work. After searching in the website, I will try to solve the issue by 7-zip command line method, hope it can help me... Anyway, thanks for your answer, it really broaden my minds :-)